# How to you paste in List-Mode with Nautilus in Gnome3? In other words... Where do I rightclick to "Paste"? (Not "Paste into Folder...")

Tags: gnome, nautilus

In Gnome2 and Unity, you could right click in List Mode and the "Paste" option appeared. How do you make it appear in the new Nautilus? (There is only "Paste into folder" now)

[image]

Comment: I found this but ;(.... I dont know... anyone know how to paste in the new Nautilus? Maybe Ubuntu 1710 can also add a copy/paste button at the top?   https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2015-June/461913.html

Comment: As there is no 'free' space to click on you either go up one dir. so target dir. is visible & can be clicked on or just use the menu > Edit > paste or use ctrl+v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must right click on parent folder, in your case **.config** button and choose **Paste into Folder** Button.

Comment: Yeah, but is there a place I can click to "Paste Here"? The old version allowed me to click at the bottom (where there are no files and "Paste Here")

Comment: I am sorry to disappoint you, but it is impossible to see **Paste Here** option, if your list is full enough

Comment: Thanks, yeah its unfortunate. If you switch to ICON view, there is "Paste Here", but LIST VIEW they removed it when the list fills up the screen :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a **trick!** :)  What you do is you enter the folder, but ***before the icons load*** quickly press rightclick. This is how you **paste** into the folder.

Comment: I suspect that trying to do this often will lead to problems with not knowing where your files have gone.

Comment: Yes you are right. Bummer... its hard because  I have to rush and right click it which is difficult for carple tunnel